# Is passing a file 'with open' to function possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been told using `with open() as file` is the way to go while opening files in Python. However, does this also work if the file is passed to a function? And does it close properly after the function is done?

```py
def file_function(the_file):
    # Do something with the file...

def main():
    with open('filename') as the_file:
        file_function(the_file)
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: One of the most typical use cases is `with open('foo.json') as f: json.load(f)`… So, yeah…

Comment: It works, I just wonder if the file is closed properly and if this is the way to go

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 1):

> However, does this also work if the file is passed to a function? And does it close properly after the function is done?

Of course it does. The following:

```py
with EXPR as TARGET:
    DO_SOMETHING(TARGET)
```

is roughly equivalent to

```py
MANAGER = (EXPR)
TARGET = MANAGER.__enter__()
has_exc = False
try:
    DO_SOMETHING(TARGET)
except:
    has_exc = True
    if not MANAGER.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
        raise
finally:
    if not has_exc:
        MANAGER.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

so as you can see, the `__exit__` method (which in the case of `open(...)` is a small wrapper around `.close()`) is always called after `DO_SOMETHING` exits (properly or not). Not before, not in the meantime, always after.

For more information about the `with` statement read the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Answer (score 1):

The [with-statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement) generates a context. The context contains some functions that will be run on entering and exiting the block.

So any object implementing the proper `__enter__` and `__exit__` can be used in a with statement. The exit method is called regardless of whether an error has been raised in the inner block.

So your code is fine. Even if the inner function errors, the file will still be closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the it will be properly closed automatically after the operations within the `with open` finished executing.

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
# operations
f.close()
```

is the same as

```
with open("example.txt", "r"):
    # operations
```